# Google Line Chart - How to display data to linegraph

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, google-visualization, linechart

See the following data.[DataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5PaE.png)

How do I input this data into Google Line Charts with filter for each Column AND filter for the Dates.

I would like my graph to have x-axis of dates and y-axis with the percentage. Also each row of data is its own line in the line graph. Is this possible?

Below is a snippet part of my code:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(response,false);

      var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard-div'));



      var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'Table',
        'containerId': 'table-div',
        'options': {'backgroundColor': 'lightgrey'}
      });

      var numCol = [3];
      for (var i = 10; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        numCol.push(i);
        }

      var line = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
        'containerId': 'linechart-div',
        'view': {'columns': numCol},
        'options': {'backgroundColor': 'lightgrey', 'title': 'InterCarrier Trunk Capacity Graph', 'explorer': { 
            'actions': ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
            'axis': 'horizontal',
            }}
      });




      var Slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
        'containerId': 'slider-div1',
        'options': {
          'filterColumnLabel': '3/1/2020'

         }
      });

      var Slider2 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
        'containerId': 'slider-div2',
        'options': {
          'filterColumnLabel': '3/2/2020'

         }
      });

      var Slider3 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
        'containerId': 'slider-div3',
        'options': {
          'filterColumnLabel': '3/3/2020'

         }
      });

      var Slider4 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
        'containerId': 'slider-div4',
        'options': {
          'filterColumnLabel': '3/4/2020'

         }
      });
```

[Chart Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gqpU.png)

Comment: it's possible, see [controls and dashboards](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls)...

Comment: The dates are not in it's own column. How do I make the dates on X axis of the line graph with also a filter?

Comment: you'll have to manipulate the data, where is the data stored and how are you retrieving it? and please share any relevant code...

Comment: I have uploaded part of my code and a picture of my graph. Right now I am using a ColumnChart to display my data because I cannot get the x-axis to be the date. LineChart is my goal and as you can see I want the legend and X-axis of my current graph swapped. Also my data comes from google sheets which I am extracting from.